# Neo4j simple paths between two nodes without specifying the maximum length

Tags: java, graph, neo4j

We have recently started using Neo4j database and I am using the below code (uses [GraphAlgoFactory](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphalgo/GraphAlgoFactory.html#dijkstra-org.neo4j.graphdb.PathExpander-org.neo4j.graphalgo.CostEvaluator-) API) for finding all the possible paths to reach from one Node to another Node :

```
Node node1 = db.getNodeById(startNodeId);
Node node2 = db.getNodeById(endNodeId);

PathExpander<Object> pathExpander = PathExpanders.allTypesAndDirections();
PathFinder<Path> pathsFinder = GraphAlgoFactory.allSimplePaths(pathExpander, 10);
Iterable<Path> paths = pathsFinder.findAllPaths(node1, node2);
//Iterate all paths
```

As you can notice, in the above code, for `allSimplePaths()` we need to provide the maximum length (I have given as `10`) as input which I will not be able to know prior to finding the paths.

So, my question is how can we retrieve all of the simple paths between two nodes without specifying the maximum length?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a very high value for the maximum depth.

However, generally, the greater the maximum depth, the greater the risk that the algorithm will take too long or run out of memory. That is because the search area grows exponentially by depth. For example, if on average the nodes you are interested in have N neighbors, then at depth x you will have to evaluate N^x neighboring nodes (and also remember what you have discovered thus far).

Comment: I thought that is (using high value) the second (but not a good) option. I am looking for a better way to handle this. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "better" alternative. Any algorithm to find all "simple paths" (i.e., all paths with no repeating nodes) between two nodes has to try all applicable paths, which can be arbitrarily long. So, unless you allow any suitable algorithm to use a high max depth, you will not be able to get complete results.